# Add class to <html> with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

How do you add a class to the `<html>` root element using Javascript?

Comment: this was one of the questions I asked when I started out. I never did find a good place that mentioned it. I am glad to see it here.

Comment: Just curious - why would you want to do this?

Comment: @David To add a fallback in case Modernizr doesn't load.  Modernizr adds the class "js" when it loads.

Comment: You should really add the class "no-js" to your markup if you are using modernizr. (If modernizr loads it will remove this class)

Comment: @Kevin - Already did.  Go [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/)!

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Like this:

```
var root = document.getElementsByTagName( 'html' )[0]; // '0' to assign the first (and only `HTML` tag)

root.setAttribute( 'class', 'myCssClass' );
```

Or use this as your 'setter' line to preserve any previously applied classes: (thanks @ama2)

```
root.className += ' myCssClass';
```

Or, depending on the required browser support, you can use the `classList.add()` method:

```
root.classList.add('myCssClass');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList
http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist

UPDATE:

A more elegant solution for referencing the `HTML` element might be this:

```
var root = document.documentElement;
root.className += ' myCssClass';
// ... or:
//  root.classList.add('myCssClass');
//
```

Comment: FYI, classlist.add/.remove doesn't work on document.documentElement.

Comment: @AndyMercer It's `classList.add` (camel case).

Comment: Yes obviously that was a typo. But what I said is still correct. `classList` doesn't work on document.documetElement.

Comment: I tried it in three different browsers before replying, so it wasn't "obviously a typo." (Chrome, Firefox, Safari--`root.classList.add('myCssClass')` worked in all three.) Are you using IE?

Comment: `document.documentElement.classList.add` seems to work fine here. Have browsers in 2018 started supporting this?

Answer (score 23):

```
document.documentElement.classList.add('myCssClass');
```

`classList` is supported since ie10: https://caniuse.com/#search=classlist

Answer (score 22):

This should also work:

```
document.documentElement.className = 'myClass';
```

[Compatibility](https://web.archive.org/web/20170413002413/http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Document/documentElement#compatibilitysection).

**Edit:**

IE 10 reckons it's readonly; yet:

[image: It worked!?]

Opera works:

[image: Works]

I can also confirm it works in:

- Chrome 26
- Firefox 19.02
- Safari 5.1.7

Comment: Your example has INVISIBLE CHARACTERS, namely `U+200B` after the final apostrophe, causing it to fail compilation in webpack and other compilers!

Comment: @entozoon how strange!  Thanks for pointing that out.  I've fixed it now :)

Answer (score 8):

I'd recommend that you take a look at **[jQuery](http://jquery.com/)**.

jQuery way:

```
$("html").addClass("myClass");
```

Comment: You don't need jQuery to select an element with JavaScript.

Comment: jQuery is infact easy to learn, and is used most of the time anyway, these days. But yes, you don't need it for this task ;)

Comment: yeah, right, we know what jquery is, but answering a purely javascript question with "learn jquery" is what surprised me :)

Comment: @aebersold I agree that jQuery is easy to learn and use, but at 50K to download (plus an additional request) just to add a class, it's a bit of overkill IMHO.

Comment: He asked for "with JavaScript" not "with a JavaScript framework"

Comment: @Mick thanks for pointing this out a decade after I wrote this answer.

Answer (score 7):

You should append class not overwrite it

```
var headCSS = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].getAttribute("class") || "";
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].setAttribute("class",headCSS +"foo");
```

I would still recommend using jQuery to avoid browser incompatibilities

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].classList.add('theme-dark');
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].classList.remove('theme-dark')
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].classList.toggle('theme-dark')
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
<script>
    (function () {
        try {
            const mode = localStorage.getItem('darkMode');
            if (!JSON.parse(mode)) return;
            document.documentElement.classList.add('dark');
        } catch (e) {}
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: This answer just repeats what was already answered a decade(!) ago. All the rest is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score -3):

**With Jquery**...
You can add class to html elements like this:

`$(".divclass").find("p,h1,h2,h3,figure,span,a").addClass('nameclassorid');`

**nameclassorid** no point or # at the beginning